# How to disable references in poedit

Tags: php, locale, gettext, poedit

How to disable adding references to *.po file? in POedit?

poedit adds references, but do not need it.

Example of my gettext file:

```
#: ../../../tests/cases/Command/SysInfoTest.php:49
#: ../../../tests/cases/Command/SysInfoTest.php:238
#: ../../../tests/cases/Command/SysInfoTest.php:248
msgid "ERROR__SYSINFO__INVALID_SAVE_PATH"
msgstr "The source type for the request is invalid."
```

and here is how I would like to:

```
 msgid "ERROR__SYSINFO__INVALID_SAVE_PATH"
 msgstr "The source type for the request is invalid."
```

is there any solutions? or do I need to parse and delete references manually?

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) documents the `--no-location` flag for `xgettext` that does exactly what you want.